# Parsing CSV Data to another CSV based on Samaccountmatch

Tags: powershell

I have 2 csv's, 1 from exchange and 1 from AD. I am querying for samaccountname, emailaddress, enabled in AD. I am querying for samaccountname, primarysmtpaddress where recipienttype is 'usermailbox'.

After these are compared it spits out a 3rd csv based on the mismatches it finds. I need to parse the primarysmtpaddress from the exchange csv to the next column and only the addresses based on the samaccountname.

Also, any suggestions are welcome. First time here :)

## AD Script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
$SamAccountPath = "Path\get_adusers.csv"
$SamAccountPathE = "Path\get_adusers_edit.csv"
$Folder = "Path\mismatch_script"
$logfile = "Path\mismatch_script\get-user.txt"

Try{
if (Test-Path $Folder)
{}
else
{
    New-Item -Path "$Folder" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}
} Catch {
Write-Output "Could not create log folder" | Out-File $logfile -Append

}
Try
{
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory

} Catch {
  Write-Output "Could not import ActiveDirectory module." | Out-File  $logfile -Append

}

Try{
Get-Aduser -filter * -properties Samaccountname, emailaddress, enabled | ? { $_.enabled -eq $true } | select samaccountname, emailaddress |`
?{$_.emailaddress -ne $null} | Sort-Object samaccountname |`
Export-Csv -Path $SamAccountPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null
Get-Content $SamAccountPath | select -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Samaccountname','primarysmtpaddress' | Export-Csv -Path $SamAccountPathE -NoTypeInformation -Force |Out-Null
Remove-Item $SamAccountPath -Force

} Catch {

Write-Output "Could not get ad users" | Out-File  $logfile -Append
}        

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0 -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; Path\get-exuser_information.ps1"
```

## Exchange Script

```
$AliasPath =  "Path\get_exusers.csv"
$SamAccountPath = "Path\get_adusers_edit.csv"
$MismatchPath = "Path\get_diff.csv"
$logfile = "Path\get-user.txt"

$mboxes = get-mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -identity
$samobj.Samaccountname | Where-Object {$_.recipienttype -eq "UserMailbox"} | select samaccountname, primarysmtpaddress
$ExUserL = Import-Csv $AliasPath 
$AdUserL = Import-Csv $SamAccountPath | Where-Object {$_.samaccountname}
$samobj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 'Samaccountname' = $_.samaccountname }
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ExUserL -DifferenceObject    
$AdUserL = Import-Csv $SamAccountPath | Where-Object {$_.samaccountname}


Try {
ForEach-Object{

Import-Csv $SamAccountPath | select samaccountname | Out-Null
}
$mboxes | Sort-Object samaccountname | Export-Csv $AliasPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null

} Catch {
Write-Output "Could not get mailboxes" | Out-File  $logfile -Append
}

Try {

$compare | foreach {
if ($_.sideindicator -eq '<=')
{$_.sideindicator = ''
$_.samaccountname = ''
$_.primarysmtpaddress = ''
}

if ($_.sideindicator -eq '=>')
{$_.sideindicator = "Mismatch"}

}

$compare | Export-Csv $MismatchPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null

} Catch {
Write-Output "Could not compare ex and ad csvs" | Out-File $logfile -Append
}

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "server" -Attachments $MismatchPath -From "email" -to "email" -Subject "Mismatch Report"
```

## I rewrote it and found this solution:

```
    #Globals for warnings/error action
    $WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    #import activedirectory cmdlets
    import-module -name activedirectory

    #Collects Exchange cmdlets into PSSession and imports it into the current session. 
    $exchangeuser = "user"
    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://exchange/powershell/ -Authentication kerberos
    import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber

    #Declare paths
    $MismatchPath =  "Path\AD_EX_Mismatches.csv"
    $MismatchPathE = "Path\AD_EX_MismatchesE.csv"

    #Creates empty array
    $errorstatus = @()

    #Gets all mailboxes that are 'UserMailboxes' and not 'Contacts' it  then pipes sam and psmtp to get-aduser. The @{n="";e={}} is creating a table and running an expression or cmdlet.
    $gUser = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.recipienttype -eq "UserMailbox"} | select samaccountname, primarysmtpaddress,@{n="ADEmail";e = {Get-ADuser $_.samaccountname -Properties emailaddress | select -ExpandProperty emailaddress}},@{n="Error";e={$errorstatus}}

    #Foreach object (Samaccountname,primarysmtpaddress,emailaddress,error). Check if the conditions are met, if so, output the $gUser.Error to the CSV
    $gUser | ForEach-Object {

    if($_.ADEmail -ne $_.PrimarySmtpAddress){
    $_.Error = "Mismatch"
    } 

    if($_.ADEmail -eq ' '){
    $_.Error = "Corrupted"
    }
    }
    $gUser | Export-Csv $MismatchPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null

    #Finds blanks in the csv and re-exports it to a new path.
    Import-Csv $MismatchPath | Where-Object {$_.samaccountname -and $_.primarysmtpaddress -and $_.error -notlike ""} | select * | export-csv $MismatchPathE -NoTypeInformation -Force

    #Finds EX session and removes it
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

    #Send email with args
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "mailserver" -Attachments $MismatchPathE -From "emailaddress" -to "email address" -Subject "Mismatch Report" -Body "Attached is a report of mismatches of email addresses between AD and Exchange."
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review or is something wrong with your current code?

Comment: I need to figure out how to take data from 1 csv ("Path\get_exusers.csv")  "primarysmtpaddress" column. Then add it correlating to the mismatch file that is generated from a compare-object of ("Path\get_exusers.csv") and ("Path\get_adusers.csv"). The end result is the mismatch csv (Path\get_diff.csv). I need to take the "primarysmtpaddress" column from the ("Path\get_exusers.csv") and only add the addresses correlating to the "samaccountname" column in the mismatch csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Globals for warnings/error action
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    #import activedirectory cmdlets
import-module -name activedirectory


#Collects Exchange cmdlets into PSSession and imports it into the current session. 
$exchangeuser = "user"
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://EX/powershell/ -Authentication kerberos
import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber

#Declare paths
$MismatchPath =  "E:\Utilities\Scripts\Set_DashboardData\Mismatch\1.csv"
$MismatchPathE = "E:\Utilities\Scripts\Set_DashboardData\Mismatch\1E.csv"
$ReportPath = "E:\Reports\Exchange\EXDashboard\"

#Creates empty array
$errorstatus = @()
$Fix = @()
#Gets all mailboxes that are 'UserMailboxes' and not 'Contacts' it then pipes sam and psmtp to get-aduser. The @{n="";e={}} is creating a table and running an expression or cmdlet.
$gUser = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.recipienttype -eq "UserMailbox"} | select samaccountname, primarysmtpaddress,@{n="ADEmail";e = {Get-ADuser $_.samaccountname -Properties emailaddress | select -ExpandProperty emailaddress}},@{n="Error";e={$errorstatus}}

#Foreach object (Samaccountname,primarysmtpaddress,emailaddress,error). Check if the conditions are met, if so, output the $gUser.Error to the CSV
$gUser | ForEach-Object {

if($_.ADEmail -ne $_.PrimarySmtpAddress){
$_.Error = "Mismatch"
}

if($_.ADEmail -eq ' '){
$_.Error = "Corrupted"
  }
 }
$gUser | Export-Csv $MismatchPath -NoTypeInformation -Force | Out-Null

#Finds blanks in the csv and re-exports it to a new path.
Import-Csv $MismatchPath | Where-Object {$_.samaccountname -and $_.primarysmtpaddress -and $_.error -notlike ""}  | export-csv $MismatchPathE -NoTypeInformation -Force

#Deletes original file
Remove-Item $MismatchPath -Force 

#Finds EX session and removes it
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```